# How to specify regions in MATLAB compass

Tags: matlab, user-input, compass

I want to use the MATLAB compass function and user-input to plot readings in a specific region. For example, if I press 1, the reading should be in the `(45,135)` region, if I press 2 it's from `(135,225)` up until 45 again or something like that.

```
if x=1; y=(+,+); else if x=2; y=(+,-)
```

I only was able to get the reading and after that I put `(-,-)` or `(+,+)` with the reading `y=(-15,-70)`, but the problem is that I couldn't specify them in degrees from, for example, `(45,135)`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: When I upload my reading even if it is for example (-9,-90) and i want to plot it in the first region it changes the reading to (9,90). I hope this is fine thank you for your support.